# New addition to rune pages for season 9

Tags: league-of-legends

Is anybody aware of what the new additions will be to the rune pages in preparation for the next ranked season? From what I've heard it's an additional tree to select from but I'm not sure what you can chose from.

Comment: While this content is not live, the changes are currently visible and available on the [Public Beta Environment](http://www.surrenderat20.net/p/current-pbe-balance-changes.html#balance).

Comment: @Yuuki Thanks, I was aware of that, I should have put that in my message. I wasn't in the position to move onto the PBE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be too many changes with runes this upcoming season. The biggest difference is that the set bonuses that you get from specific rune path combos will now be separated out into their own stat block.

For example, in season 8, if you took the Precision as your primary rune tree, and Domination as your secondary, your would gain 6 AD/10 AP adaptive plus 9% bonus attack speed. However, if you took Precision and Inspiration instead, you would get 18% attack speed.

In season 9, instead of being locked into those stats based on which rune trees you choose, you will get to pick directly from a set of stats to bring into the game.

[image: Season 9 Rune Stats]

In the middle bottom of the image above, you can see that there are 3 new rows of icons to choose. You get to choose one from each row. The bonuses are currently:

- Row 1: 10 Adaptive (6 AD or 10 AP), 8% Attack Speed, 1-10% CDR (lvls 1-18).
- Row 2: 10 Adaptive, 5 Armor, 6 Magic Resist.
- Row 3: 15-90 HP (lvls 1-18), 5 Armor, 6 Magic Resist